# Read context.xml in Spring Boot Embedded Tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8, embedded-tomcat-8

While converting non spring application to Spring Boot want to use existing context.xml file in embedded tomcat.

Using Spring Boot 1.5.1 and Tomcat 8.5.11

TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory Configuration

```
@Bean
public TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory() {

        @Override
        protected TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(Tomcat tomcat) {
            tomcat.enableNaming();
            return super.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(tomcat);
        }

        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            // Try-1 - Not Working
            if (context instanceof StandardContext) {
                StandardContext standardContext = (StandardContext) context;
                standardContext.setCopyXML(true);
            }

            // Try-2 - Not Working
            context.setConfigFile(Paths.get("/META-INF/context.xml").toFile().toURI().toURL());

            // Try-3 - Working - But due to very large and multiple configuration, java config will be cumbersome
            ContextResource resource = new ContextResource();
            resource.setName("jdbc/myDB");
            resource.setType(DataSource.class.getName());
            resource.setAuth("Container");
            resource.setProperty("username", "user111");
            resource.setProperty("password", "password111");
            resource.setProperty("driverClassName", "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            context.getNamingResources().addResource(resource);
       }
}
```

Method for checking database connection,

```
public void checkDb() {
    Context initContext = new InitialContext();
    Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
    DataSource datasource = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/myDB");
    Connection con = datasource.getConnection();
}
```

So how to load existing context.xml in Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

I think as a variant you can configure path to your tomcat dir and use it in spring boot [spring doc with embedded container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-web-applications).

Comment: I also try to add server.tomcat.basedir = target/tomcat in application.properties and added context.xml in conf directory but that doesn't help.